# Can't get pixel color from canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas, pixel

I'm having trouble getting color information from pixels on a canvas.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('frame');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
var source = $("#image").attr("src");

img.src = source;
$(img).load(function() {
   context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
});

var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
var pix = imgd.data;

for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
  console.log(pix[i] +", "+ pix[i+1] +", "+ pix[i+2] +", "+ pix[i+3]);
}
```

(So I'm getting the src from another image on the page and drawing it on the canvas. Which is working fine, I can see the image on the canvas.)

To my understanding, each time the for loop runs, this code should log the red, green, blue, and alpha values to the console for the first 50X50 pixels.

Instead, all I get are zeros.

[image: zeros]

etc...

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
$(img).load(function() {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var imgd = context.getImageData(0, 0, 50, 50);
    var pix = imgd.data;

    for (var i = 0, n = pix.length; i < n; i += 4) {
      console.log(pix[i] +", "+ pix[i+1] +", "+ pix[i+2] +", "+ pix[i+3]);
    }
});
```

At the time your image has loaded the loop is probably done with the buffer iterating so the buffer will be empty due to the image loading is asynchronously.

Besides from that there is the possibility of CORS restrictions (you need to check in console to see if there's any security errors).

Comment: Literally two seconds after realizing this, I saw that you posted it haha 

Thanks so much, works perfectly!

Comment: @user1868084 no problem, it happens :)